# SSAS cube development

Tags: ssas, cube, olap-cube, cubes

I am developing an SSAS cube for the product I am working on.

I have faced the below problems:

1. In the product you can build organization unit chart. This organization unit will be used as a dimension in the cube. In my research I found that I can build a cube grammatically using C#. My question is that what is the best approach to build a dynamic dimension.
2. In the product, we have a role based permission. A user can see data based on his role. How can I implement this feature in the cube? Currently, any body can read all the data from the cube.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic dimensions are possible in SSAS. You would be able to show the members based on the roles that are desired. This is done using "Dynamic dimension security". You'd be able to write an MDX in the "Dimension data" tab.
http://bidn.com/Blogs/analysis-services-dynamic-security